# Flutter Box with Navigation on pressed

Tags: flutter

I am writing a flutter app where i want create boxes like grid and each can be click to navigate on different screen.

Similar to below example

[image]

I am a beginner, how can i achieve this. Can you please share some pointer. I went through Documentation but if you can help me with what to search for I can read. or if you can share some exmaple.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap each box widget with an inkwell and add an onTap to it where you can call the navigation ie:

```
      InkWell(
          onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
          child: Container(
            height: 25.0,
            width: 80.0,
            child: Text('CANCEL'),
        ),
```

[InkWell](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html)

[Gesture Detector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html)